# Pinot fasthll and distinctcounthll returns different values

Tags: olap, presto

we are using pinot hll, and got suggested to switch from fasthll to distinctcounthll, but we got the count very different, with the same condition we have 1000x difference.
Example:

```
SELECT fasthll(my_hll), distinctcounthll(my_hll)
FROM counts_table WHERE timestamp >= 1500768000
```

I get results:

```
"aggregationResults": [
    {
        "function": "fastHLL_my_hll",
        "value": "68685244"
    }, {
        "function": "distinctCountHLL_my_hll",
        "value": "50535"
    }]
```

Could anyone suggest what's the big difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to [pinot-issue-5153](https://github.com/apache/incubator-pinot/issues/5153).

FastHll will convert one string into a hyperloglog object, which may represent thousand unique values. DistinctCountHLL treats string as a value, not hyperloglog object, so it will return the approximation of how many unique hyperloglog serialized strings, the value should be close to your total number scanned .

fasthll is deprecated because of the low performance of deserialization. You may generate BYTES type for serialized HyperLogLog using org.apache.pinot.core.common.ObjectSerDeUtils.HYPER_LOG_LOG_SER_DE.serialize(hyperLogLog) and query it with distinctcounthll